# I have an if statement and pass it, but get an error anyway, python

Tags: python

I have this if statement in python. where if `U<0` i want to pass. but if U>0 I want to know if `len(U[0])<1`. However I get an error when  `len(U) < 0` 
on the line `if len(U[0])<1:` `IndexError: index out of bounds`. but i thought it was meant to pass this so it should only look for it when `len(U)>0`. can anyone help?

```
   if len(U) < 0:
        pass
   else:
        if len(U[0])<1:
            pass
        else:
            Uli=U[0]
            list2.append(Uli)
```

Comment: You need to provide us with more code.

Comment: negate the condition and leave the pass-block out: `if U and len(U[0]) >= 1: list2.append(U[0])`

Comment: That's a very verbose way of trying to say `if U and U[0]: list2.append(U[0])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`len` returns a non-negative integer. Comparing `len(U) < 0` will always be false, so `pass` is never executed.

Instead, it goes into the `else` branch, where it tries to access the `0`th element of the possibly empty list. The error you're seeing is because the list is empty.

Consider changing `if len(U) < 0:` to `if len(U) == 0:` or simply `if len(U):` or `if not U:`.

Comment: but the array can be empty sometimes, then it will be passed

Comment: If it's empty, len would return 0, not less than zero.